# mysql geographic replication

Tags: mysql, replication, cluster-computing

I have been reading lots of docs, blogs,articles.. talking about Mysql Replication and i dont know how to solve it.

We need a failover and redundant solution to our basic data base. So the idea is to buy a new server to have some geographical failover solution.

The initial idea was to store one master database into server A and another master replica into server B, making a master-master replication. But whe want synchronous replication in order to ensure data consistency.

So we test the Mysql Cluster, but im so confused because Mysql official docs says that only should work on local networks. And the other problem is the comunications security.

We have 1.40 ms latency between the two servers.

What should be the best option?? i mean there is no safe option for synchronous redundant data bases between diffenret data centers?

How big companies solve it? or it's imposible to have geographical redundancy + failover solution  + data consistency

Thx All

Comment: The Mysql replication is already a very good compromise even if it is asynchroneous. Are you sure your kind of application needs near real-time synchronisation and a multi-master scenario? 1.4ms is a low latency, so in practise, you can setup a classical mysql replication and monitor the replication 'lateness' to be warned asap if there is a problem. If you want to distribute the load, you can setup a master-slave replication, have all writes (inserts & updates) going to the master, and reads go to the slave.

Comment: Yes, but if i setup a master-slave, first of all i dont have failover solution, and what about the data inconsistency...

Comment: You have a failover solution, if the master fails you can redirect all queries to the slave (you can later copy back new data on the master when it's back online). Can you tell me more about what you need to achieve exactly?

Comment: Yes, first of all we want a failover solution. The current data base stores basic web application info, so if it falls down user cant acces to it. Second its to increase efficency so app can read data from both data bases. But my "fear" it that for example, some one create one user into de data base (master) and then he want to login and reads from salve? what happen i we have and error into the replication? that we want synch replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master-slave scenario is already a very good solution to protect against a server failure .

If you want the slave to be used for querying in order to spread load, either you accept that the slave can have its data behind master, or you put an additional layer between your app and the database servers.

A few years ago I started to play with [Mysql-Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/). As its name indicates, it acts as a proxy, and amongst other cool things, it can do query balancing over multiple nodes while checking them for availability.

I would add, as a conclusion, that if your link between the 2 DCs is reliable and has a +/- 1.4ms lag, in practise your slave will keep updated and the delay won't be noticeable by users.

Of course, all this doesn't apply if your application does things that you didn't mention (purchase transactions, or if you are a bank;) )

(added as an answer as it was too long for a comment)

Comment: Thx! i'll check that solution. we have no large transactions so the lag shouldn't increase. Do you think that the use of Galera could be another solution?

Comment: Quite frankly, I never heard of it before, but it seems to do exactly what you want. And about transactions and lag increase, you can mitigate that by ensuring your Mysql storage engine is Innodb, not MyIsam.

Comment: Yep, its Innodb. So im going to make some tests. one using a simple master-slave and other with galera. Thaks for all the info!

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if I can help more. Else don't hesitate to mark the question as answered ;)